# Rewrtting url by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

> localhost/visvabharati/archive.html/type/notice

this is my url.I want it to rewrite as

> localhost/visvabharati/archive.php?type=notice

Please help me  how would be the htaccess

currently using

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php?url_key=index [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html$ /index.php?url_key=$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*).html-([^/]*)$ /index.php?url_key=$1&id=$2 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]
```

But its giving 500.
Please Help me sort it out
Regards

Comment: Why are you using `T=application/x-httpd-php` every where?

Comment: hii thank you for reply  im very new in this regards first time doing it,i have  removed it  too,but  nothing changed still 500,can you  guide me.

Answer (score 0):

This code here will do it for one page.

```
RewriteRule ^localhost/visvabharati/archive.html/(.+)/(.+) localhost/visvabharati/archive.php?$1=$2
```

If you need to do this for multiple pages, this should work.

```
RewriteRule ^localhost/visvabharati/(.+).html/(.+)/(.+) localhost/visvabharati/$1.php?$2=$3
```

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^localhost/visvabharati/(.+).html/(.+)/(.+) localhost/visvabharati/$1.php?$2=$3     i put  your  code like this but  still 404,thank you so much anyhow  for  ur  kind reply

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming `visvabharati` is a directory.**

Place this in `/visvabharati/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /visvabharati/

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Also **you need to remove** all the code shown in your question.

Comment: after  using this its  not  giving 404 but now its  not  able to load the  page  at all  also  the  first  landing page....not able to fetch the session,thank you so much for your  kind reply.

Comment: If there is no 404 and what do you mean by not able to load? What URL did you use for testing? Is it `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/visvabharati/`?